# discord music bot list index out of range Error

Tags: python, discord

I think that's the third time I've asked a question today

I don't know if this error happened suddenly

Because it worked out so well up until now!

Do you know why this is an error?

```
import youtube_dl
import discord
import asyncio

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('켜짐')
    print(client.user.id)
    print('--------------------------')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('핑크야 들어와'):
        await message.author.voice.channel.connect()
        await message.channel.send('빠밤')

    if message.content.startswith('핑크야 나가'):

        for vc in client.voice_clients:
            if vc.guild == message.guild:
                voice = vc

        await voice.disconnect()
        await message.channel.send('힝...')

    if message.content.startswith('핑크야 재생'):

        for vc in client.voice_clients:
            if vc.guild == message.guild:
                voice = vc
        url = message.content.split(" ")[1]

        option = {'format': 'bestaudio/best', 'postprocessors': [
            {'preferredcodec': 'mp3', 'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio', 'preferredquality': '320', }],
                  'outtmpl': "file/" + url.split('=')[1] + '.mp3'}

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(option) as ydl:

            ydl.download([url])

            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)

            title = info["title"]

        voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("file/" + url.split('=')[1] + ".mp3"))

        await message.channel.send(title + "재생할게!")


client.run("ODUxNDQ5NzU4NzMxNzMwOTU1.YL4cYQ.J3vABnUPM9Bq4mxJA0nEwaxBj2o")
```

From this error, I think it's over the length of the array, but it's definitely been working before

Or is it weird that it worked before?

But I did fix the mp4 to the mp3

I'd really appreciate it if you'd let me know more about the problem that's happened to me

**ERROR**

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\PKPMMB\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\PKPMMB\main.py", line 52, in on_message
    'outtmpl': "file/" + url.split('=')[1] + '.mp3'}
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Did you `print(url)` just before the split ? I'm sure it'll help you understand

Comment: If this is your third question today, I wonder if you've already done enough research yourself? StackOverflow should be the last step of your research and I find many posts on your topic.

Comment: I'll do my research harder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error appears when there is no "=" substring in url. When you split string around substring there is at least one element in resulting array of tokens, more if substring appears in main string. I would add check if len of url.split('=') is greater than "i" before using i-th element. As it's right now you blindly go for second value even if there is only one.